# How to run specific automation tests from testsuite using tcm.exe?

Tags: coded-ui-tests, microsoft-test-manager, tcm

I have designed Coded UI tests in Visual Studio 2012. I have associated them with manual tests from Test Manager.

1. How to run only automation tests with priority = 1 from some test suite?
2. How to run only testcases which were marked failed by bugs in previous test runs?

I want to run tests using command line something like this:

```
tcm run /create /title:"Nightly Run" /planid:1 /suiteid:5 /configid:13 /settingsname:"<Name of your automated test settings>" /testenvironment:"<Name of a matching environment>" /collection:<CollectionURL> /teamproject:<Team Project name>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the Agent and Controller configures for MTM (Microsoft Test Manager)?

If so, well you can do that from MTM. Create a Query-based test suite with the criteria as you described #1 and #2, this will generate a test suite for you. You can then select the tests in that suite, right-click and run the tests. This is what I'm doing today.

If you want to do this using command line options, then maybe look into how you can call that query-based test suite. I never used cmd line so far.

Comment: Thank you for your ansver but I have resolved the problem using TFS API already.